# Override Angular HttpParams

Tags: angular

I want to make sure the query params that are encoded on the UI are decoded on the API to the exact same object, so I want to use the same tool to encode and decode it. The issue is that Angular formats all of the params following the internal logic of `HttpParams` and even though you can pass a custom encoder, the logic there still wraps every value into an array, which breaks the identical outcome I am going for during decoding. Is there any way to override the query parameters specifically without providing an entire custom HTTP client?

Comment: Would encoding the params object and passing to `HttpParams` as a single `string` parameter work for you?

Comment: The params property of the request sadly only accepts an `HttpParams` object

Comment: Passing the encoded object as a single `string` param *on* the `HttpParams` object; I should have been more clear.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't catch that. I'm afraid, though technically feasible, this approach would be rejected as one that breaks general best practices and makes the API less usable for direct consumers.

Comment: Oh, agreed, but if it were possible, it would beat re-implementing the serialization portion of `HttpClient`. I'm afraid I don't have a second-best answer. Could you post a sample showing your object structure and how you're expecting it to get serialized into a request?